# Detect who triggered CodePipeline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I have a basic CodePipeline with 2 stages, a CodeCommit source and a CodeDeploy with some scripts running before and after the deployment. I would like to know if it's doable to detect whether a human triggered the pipeline using the AWS CodePipeline console or if the scheduler of CloudWatch did it? By the way, I would like to do it in my CodeDeploy scripts.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use AWS CloudTrail to monitor who issue the call to the `StartPipelineExecution` API. It would generate a event like this:

```json
[
    {
        "eventVersion": "1.08",
        "userIdentity": "{type=AssumedRole, principalid=***********:john.doe@bayer.com, arn=arn:aws:sts::247661476062:assumed-role/root-user/john.doe, accountid=xxxxxxxxx, accesskeyid=xXXXXXXXXXXXX, username=null, sessioncontext={attributes={creationdate=2023-04-05 21:00:11.000, mfaauthenticated=false}, sessionissuer={type=Role, principalid=AROATTKOGHDPHTDMFBCX6, arn=arn:aws:iam::247661476062:role/standard-user, accountid=247661476062, username=root-user}, ...}",
        "eventTime": "2023-04-10 21:48:41.000",
        "eventSource": "codepipeline.amazonaws.com",
        "eventName": "StartPipelineExecution",
        "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.1.0",
        "userAgent": "AWS Internal",
        "errorCode": "",
        "errorMessage": "",
        "requestParameters": "{clientRequestToken=6dba9fb5-9055-4d67-c1f6-78da10026a54, name=code-pipeline-name}",
        "responseElements": "{pipelineExecutionId=9d581804-d8b9-486c-a815-878998fbaf34}",
        "additionalEventData": "",
        "requestID": "**",
        "eventID": "**",
        "readOnly": "false",
        "resources": "",
        "eventType": "AwsApiCall",
        "apiVersion": "",
        "managementEvent": "true",
        "recipientAccountId": "247661476062",
        "sharedEventID": "",
        "annotation": "",
        "vpcEndpointId": "",
        "serviceEventDetails": "",
        "addendum": "",
        "edgeDeviceDetails": "",
        "insightDetails": "",
        "eventCategory": "Management",
        "tlsDetails": "",
        "sessionCredentialFromConsole": "true"
    }
]
```

With this you could check wether the principal is a user or an aws service, and then take an action.

Good starting points are this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudtrail-logs.html) and this [aws cli doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudtrail/index.html)